# Problem compiling TikZ diagram using template

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, templates

This is my first input here. I have a problem compiling this document, where particularly the TikZ graph comes messed up (no graphics at all and labels superimposed). I am using TeXstudio with MiKTex 2.9 in Windows 7 and applying the standard commands:

1. pdflatex: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
2. LaTex: latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex ;  and later DVI->PDF

No errors come from both compilations only overfull \hbox in the pdflatex and in the latex command and additional seemingly unrelated warning "Drivers other than 'pdftex.def' are not supported". When doing the DVI->PDF several warnings are displayed but no reference to TikZ.
I know the graphic is ok as I could display it using other template; however this is the recommended thesis template. I have updated all Latex packages, I would like to know where the problem is, I believe some problem with the class or the compilation commands.

The code of the files are:
For the main document "phd_thesis_format.tex":

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,12pt,mycolours,final]{mythesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvips]{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[noBBpl]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hang]{caption}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[notref,color]{showkeys}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}
\include{chapterOne}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{harvard_dcu}
\end{document}
```

For the Chapter with a simplified graph "ChapterOne.tex"

```
\chapter{Chapter One}

\begin{chaptersummmary}
\PARstart{C}{hapter} summary goes here.
\end{chaptersummmary}

\section{Chapter One section}
\label{section2.1} Create another section in this chapter
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=1.0,auto=left, node distance = 1.5cm]
  \tikzset{
    arn_n/.style = {circle, black,  draw=black,  % font=\sffamily\bfseries,
      fill=blue!20, text width=1.5em, text centered},% arbre rouge noir, noeud noir
    arn_x/.style = {rectangle, draw=black,
      minimum width=1.2em, minimum height=1.2em} % arbre rouge noir, nil
  }
  \node[arn_x] (7) {};  
  \node[arn_n, right of=7] (8) {$y_{i-1}$};
  \node[arn_x, right of=8] (9) [label=above:{$\psi_i^2(y_{i-1},y_i)$}] {};
  \node[arn_n, right of=9] (10) {$ y_i$};
  \node[arn_x, right of=10] (11) {};
  \node[arn_n, right of=11] (12) {$y_{i+1}$};  
  \node[arn_x, right of=12] (13) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph indicating propagation of messages}
\label{Fig2.FWprop}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Chapter One subsection}
\label{subsection2.1.1} Chapter 2 subsection goes here.
```

The class file which I have reduced from more than 800 lines, my grasp in Latex is not so great to continue chopping, from here on I get other unrelated errors.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mythesis}[2005/09/05 School of Electrical and Electronic Engineering -- University of Adelaide]
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{calc}

\newif\ifmydraft\mydraftfalse
\DeclareOption{mydraft}{\mydrafttrue}

\newcommand\docsize{}  % to allow 10pt or 11pt to be specified as option
\typeout{Modified by Greg Harmer, 2000}
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\docsize{10pt}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\docsize{11pt}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\docsize{12pt}}
%  Prepare to load the standard report class (12pt):
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ExecuteOptions{12pt}         % define 12pt as the default doc size
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass[\docsize]{report}  % load report.cls
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  The following sections are revisions or additions to report.cls
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PAGE LAYOUT
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength\voffset{-1.0in}
\setlength\hoffset{-1.0in}

\setlength\topmargin{20.0mm-4.0mm}
\setlength\headheight{5.00mm}
\setlength\headsep{7.00mm}

\setlength\footskip{10.00mm}
\setlength\textheight{\paperheight
                       -\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep
                       -\footskip-5.0mm-\topmargin}

% SIDE MARGINS:
\marginparsep 1mm
\if@twoside
   \setlength\oddsidemargin{3cm}
   \setlength\evensidemargin{2cm}
   \setlength\marginparwidth{1.5cm}
   \ifmydraft
      % Make room for marginal notes
      \setlength\oddsidemargin{2.5cm}
      \setlength\evensidemargin{2.5cm}
      \setlength\marginparwidth{2.25cm}
   \fi
\else
   \setlength\oddsidemargin{2.5cm}
   \setlength\evensidemargin{2.5cm}
   \setlength\marginparwidth{2.25cm}
\fi

\setlength\textwidth{\paperwidth-\oddsidemargin-\evensidemargin}

% Line spacing and par seps, gph.
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.33333}
\newcommand\setmyparsep{\parskip0.4\baselineskip\@plus0ex\@minus 0.5ex}
\newcommand\setmytightparsep{\parskip0.2\baselineskip\@minus0.5ex}
\setlength\parindent{0ex}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  Headings stuff. Added by gph.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand\blob{\rule[-0.2\unitlength]{1in}{0.8\unitlength}}
\newcommand\rblob{\begin{picture}(0,0)
                    \setlength{\unitlength}{25mm}
                    %\put(0,-\value{chapter}){\blob}
                    \put(0.127,-\value{chapter}){\blob}
                  \end{picture}}


\fancyhf{} % delete current setting for header and footer
\fancyhead[LO]{\headerfont\chaptername\space\thechapter}
\fancyhead[LE]{\headerfont\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\headerfont\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footerfont{Page\space\thepage}}
\ifmydraft\fancyfoot[C]{\footerfont{Fancy\draftcomment}}\fi
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt} % make space for the rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\addtolength{\footskip}{0.5pt} % make space for the rule


\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
   \fancyhead{} % get rid of headers
   \fancyfoot{}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line.
   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
   \ifmydraft\fancyfoot[C]{\footerfont{Plain\draftcomment}}\fi
   \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footerfont{Page\space\thepage}}
   \addtolength{\footskip}{0.5pt}}

\fancypagestyle{chapterstart}{%
   \fancyhead{} % get rid of headers
   \fancyhead[RO]{\chapterblobcolor\rblob}
   \fancyfoot{}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line.
   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
   \ifmydraft\fancyfoot[C]{\footerfont{Chapter Start\draftcomment}}\fi
   \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footerfont{Page\space\thepage}}
   \addtolength{\footskip}{0.5pt}}


\fancypagestyle{special}{%
   \fancyhead{} % get rid of headers
   \fancyfoot{}
   \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\headerfont\leftmark}
   \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footerfont{Page\space\thepage}}
   \ifmydraft\fancyfoot[C]{\footerfont{Special\draftcomment}}\fi
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % and the line.
   \addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
   \addtolength{\footskip}{0.5pt}}

\fancypagestyle{normal}{%
   \fancyhead{} % get rid of headers
   \fancyfoot{}
   \fancyhead[LO]{\headerfont\chaptername\space\thechapter}
   \fancyhead[LE]{\headerfont\rightmark}
   \fancyhead[RO]{\headerfont\leftmark}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % and the line.
   \addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
   \addtolength{\footskip}{0.5pt}
   \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footerfont{Page\space\thepage}}
   \ifmydraft\fancyfoot[C]{\footerfont{Normal\draftcomment}}\fi}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                            SECTION HEADINGS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\chaptersize{\normalsize}
\newcommand\sectionsize{\normalsize}
\newcommand\subsectionsize{\normalsize}
\newcommand\subsubsectionsize{\normalsize}
\newcounter{firstchapter}
\setcounter{firstchapter}{0}

\newif\ifwasonecol\wasonecolfalse

% What to do for the last chapter page if blank.
\def\cleardoublepage{%
\if@twocolumn\wasonecolfalse
\else\wasonecoltrue
\fi
\onecolumn
\clearpage
\if@twoside
   \ifodd\c@page\else
      \if@twocolumn % shouldn't need to be used any more, gph.
         \hbox{}\newpage\fi
      \hbox{}
      \ifmydraft
         \vspace*{\fill}
         \begin{center}
            {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\sffamily%
            This is the last page of\space\leftmark\par%
            Next chapter is
            \ifwasonecol{one}\else{two}\fi\space
            column\par\space
            (Draft -- Page will be blank)\par}
         \end{center}
         \vspace{\fill}
      \fi
      \thispagestyle{plain}
      \newpage
   \fi
\fi
\ifwasonecol\onecolumn\else\twocolumn\fi}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  CHAPTER HEADING STUFF  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \pagestyle{normal}
                    \setmyparsep
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\thispagestyle{chapterstart}
                    \ifnum\c@firstchapter=0
                      \pagenumbering{arabic}
                      \setcounter{firstchapter}{1}
                    \fi
                    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\space}
                         \typeout{Processing\space\@chapapp\space\thechapter.\space#2}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\@chapapp\space\protect\numberline{\thechapter.}#1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \ifnum\c@chapter>1
                      \addtocontents{lof}{\hfill\hrulefill\hspace*{\fill}\par%
                      \protect\addvspace{10\p@}}\fi
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{40\p@}%
  {\parindent\z@\raggedright
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \chapterlabelfont\@chapapp\space\thechapter\par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \raggedleft\chapterfont#1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\def\vertbar{\vspace*{-50\p@}
             \vertbarcolor\rule{20mm}{100\p@}}

\def\@schapter#1{\pagestyle{special}
                 \thispagestyle{plain}
                 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\TOCchapterscolor#1}%%
                 \chaptermark{#1}
                 \typeout{\space}
                 \typeout{Processing\space#1}
                 \if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}


\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright %\normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \chapterfont#1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\font\afont=eurb8 at \docsize
\newlength\letterwidth
\newcommand{\PARstart}[1]{%
    \lettrine[lines=2,lhang=0.33,nindent=0em]{
        \dropcolor
            {\textsc{#1}}}{}}  %

% Chapter summary environment, gph.
\newlength{\chapsumwidth}
\setlength{\chapsumwidth}{\textwidth-2\leftmargin}
\newenvironment{chaptersummmary}
               {\vfill\noindent\hfill
                \minipage{\chapsumwidth}
                \setlength{\parskip}{0.3\baselineskip}
                \hrulefill\par}
               {\par\vspace{-0.3\baselineskip}\hrulefill
                \endminipage
                \hspace*{\fill}
                \vskip 50\p@
                \vspace*{\fill}
                \newpage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% SOME INITIALIZATIONS:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% make the following names uppercase:

\newcommand\black{\color{black}}
\newcommand\white{\color{white}}

   \newcommand\chaptercolor{}
   \newcommand\chapterlabelcolor{}
   \newcommand\chapterblobcolor{}
   \newcommand\sectionunderlinecolor{}
   \newcommand\sectioncolor{}
   \newcommand\sectionlabelcolor{}
   \newcommand\subsectioncolor{}
   \newcommand\subsectionlabelcolor{}
   \newcommand\subsubsectioncolor{}
   \newcommand\footercolor{}
   \newcommand\headercolor{}
   \newcommand\vertbarcolor{}
   \newcommand\titlecolor{}
   \newcommand\titlepagecolor{}
   \newcommand\captioncolor{\black}
   \newcommand\captionlabelcolor{}
   \newcommand\captionlinecolor{}
   \newcommand\figlabcolor{}
   \newcommand\tablecolor{}
   \newcommand\marginnotecolor{}
   \newcommand\margintodocolor{}
   \newcommand\dropcolor{}

% Now make the font types, gph.
\font\clfont=eurb10 at 28pt

\newcommand\chapterfont{\fontsize{36}{30}\bfseries\sffamily\chaptercolor}

\newcommand\chapterlabelfont{\normalfont\clfont\chapterlabelcolor}

\newcommand\sectionfont{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\sffamily\sectioncolor}
\newcommand\sectionlabelfont{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\sffamily\sectionlabelcolor}

\newcommand\footerfont{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily\footercolor}
\newcommand\headerfont{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily\headercolor}

\newcommand\signofffont{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily}

\newcommand\marginnotefont{\normalfont\scriptsize\sffamily\marginnotecolor}
\newcommand\margintodofont{\normalfont\scriptsize\sffamily\margintodocolor}

\newcommand\figlabelfont{\normalfont\small\bfseries\sffamily\figlabcolor}

\newcommand\captionlinefont{\bfseries\captionlinecolor}
\newcommand\tcaptionfont{\normalfont\small\sffamily\captioncolor}
\newcommand\tcaptionlabelfont{\normalfont\bfseries\small\sffamily\captionlabelcolor}

\newcommand\mycaption[2][]{\caption[{#1}]{{\captionlinefont{{#1}.}}\space{#2}}}
\endinput
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When compiling with `pdflatex` the option `dvips` does make trouble, no matter if it is given globally, or as a package option to `color` or `hyperref`.

> Rule of thumb: Don't set drivers manually, packages can choose on their own which driver to use.